# lpdf luarocks dependency installation external dependency error

Tags: pdf, lua, luarocks

I want to use lpdf dependency in the luarocks. When I am trying to install it using rockspec file following error has occurred .

lpdf - https://luarocks.org/modules/tomasguisasola/lpdf/20130702.51-1

```
    Error: Failed installing dependency: https://luarocks.org/lpdf-20130702.51-1.src.rock 
    - Could not find header file for PDFLIB
    No file pdflib.h in /usr/local/include
    No file pdflib.h in /usr/include
    No file pdflib.h in /include
    You may have to install PDFLIB in your system and/or pass PDFLIB_DIR or PDFLIB_INCDIR 
    to the luarocks command.
    Example: luarocks install lpdf PDFLIB_DIR=/usr/local
    Makefile:110: recipe for target 'install' failed
    make: *** [install] Error 1
```

I want to install in on a docker container. Can anyone share an idea on this?

Comment: lpdf needs the PDFlib Lite library but it's no longer available officially. There are copies around. Try https://github.com/Distrotech/PDFlib-Lite for instance.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am new to lua. Can you guild me to install lpdf using lua rocks. I want to create a pdf in a lua project. Is there any other alternative. I used LuaHPDF but I want to add it to a docker container. Can you give me an example of a build file in lua rocks.